# Why does console.log paste the function instead of the value?

Tags: javascript

So I'm following Douglas Crockfords lectures on JS. One of his exercises is "write a function that takes one argument, and returns a function that returns the argument". The next question is "write a function that adds from two invocations".

I got the answer to both, what I don't get is why one doesn't post to the console and the other does. Here's what I mean. This is my answer to the first question:

```
function retFunc(x){
  return function(){
    return x;
  };
}

console.log(retFunc(4));
```

This posts the following to the console:

```
function(){
   return x;
}
```

However if I change it to this, it'll post 4 to the console (which is what I wanted):

```
var idf = retFunc(4);
console.log(idf());
```

Now this is my answer to the second question:

```
function addf(x){
  return function(y){
    return x+y;
  };
}

console.log(addf(3)(4));
```

And this works, it spits out 7 to the console. My question is, why does the first one not work? And this one does? Both are functions that return another function, that finally returns a value.

Comment: Because you are returning a function, so it will paste the code and in second you're executing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does the first one not work?

First one does work, **exactly** as it should. You call a function which returns you a function, but you don't call that second function. You print it instead.

Comment: Thanks so much! Couldn't wrap my head around how this was working, and now I got it!

Comment: @firefiber: don't forget to accept helpful answers :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in your first case you are not calling the returned function, but in the second one you are

```
console.log(retFunc(4));

var idf = retFunc(4);  
console.log(idf()); // <-- note the parentheses.
```

Comment: Got it! I didn't realize this before. So basically, I'm calling just the first function, and doing that will just spit out everything after return. when calling it, I've to call it once with one set of parens, and then call again, with empty parens, yes? That'll call the second function, inside the first.

Thanks!

Comment: @firefiber "That'll call the second function, inside the first" - not really. Don't think in terms "this function is inside this function". Think in terms of expressions and values. "this piece of code, when executed, produces a function, so I can call it"

Comment: Also, remember that in _each_ of your examples, `console.log` is printing the return value. It's just that in the first case, the return value is a _function expression_ and in the other cases it's returning a _scalar value_.

Comment: To expand on @SergioTulentsev, you _can_ have a function inside another function, but it would look more like this (apologies in advance as I can't format a comment): `function foo(x) {function bar() {return x;} return bar();}` In this case calling `foo(4)` would directly return the scalar value 4, since `foo` returns the _result_ of calling `bar()` (which is defined 'inside' `foo`) instead of returning a function expression. In other words, a caller of `foo` has no direct access to `bar` (it can be considered _similar_ to (but not the same as) a private function in OOP. JavaScript is fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of console.log(retFunc(4)); try console.log(retFunc(4)**()**);
You have two nested functions. so you should call inner fucntion too.